# Finding distance between the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the point $(1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

Given the euclidian metric. $d(x,y) = ((x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2 -y_2)^2)^{1/2}$ find the distance between the point $(1,1)$ and the set $A = \{x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1^2 +x_2^2 \leq 1 \}$ Where $d(A,b) = \inf\{d(x,b) : x \in A\}$.

I have never really worked with finding the $inf$ and the only examples I can find are trivial that require no work. I know that the answer is $\sqrt{2} -1$ since we are just looking for the difference between the distance of the point from $(0,0)$ subtracted from the radius of the circle.

But I would like to be a bit more rigorous and try to apply the definition. It is not hard to see we have the following after some short calculations, but I have no idea where to go from here.

$$
d(x,b)^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 -2(x_1+x_2) +2 
$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is still pretty close to what I did to come up with my solution. If I were to change the metric being used this would not be so trivial.

Comment: actually, (in my rememberings) one can show that in a finite dimensional Hilbert space, the shortest path from a point to a convex set is a straight line (ok...) and is orthogonal to the boundary of the set. But again, for crazy metrics this will not hold.

Comment: Check your distance function. I think you mean $x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 2(x_1 + x_2) + 2$. You could then use Lagrange multipliers with the constraint $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$, as it's not hard to convince yourself the nearest point must be on the boundary.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: can we assume that the infimum is achieved on the boundary? if you could, then you can take $x_1 = \cos t, x_2 = \sin t$ so that your distance function becomes a one variable function. you know how to minimise that.

Comment: I don't want to make the assumption about any particular point in the set A's location. I just wanna break down a known example so that I can extend to other metrics. Say the taxicab or the max metric.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding what you want to do well, but it's clear the closest point on the sphere to a point outside will be on the boundary (not the topological boundary, obviously, since the sphere has none), and that is the set of points s.t. x_1^2+x_2^2=1, so d(x,b)^2=-2(x_1+x_2)+3. Then find the minimizing x_1 and x_2.

Comment: I was able to solve this after using Lagrange multipliers, and got exactly what I was expecting. I was hoping that this problem would give light to doing the same problem with another metric. say the taxi cab metric. I can get to a similar point except now the function would look something like |x-1|+|y-1|. For the same constraint.

Comment: For taxi cab I'd first try something like parametrizing the boundary of a square centered at the origin and finding the zero of the derivative of the distance between the parametrization and the point. If it worked you could take arbitrary points and get a formula.

Comment: It actually becomes a much easier problem after converting to polar coordinates. The problem reduces to minimizing the function $f(x) = |1-\cos(x)| + |1- \sin(x)| = 2 - \cos(x) - \sin(x)$ since both $\sin(x) \leq 1$ and $\cos(x) \leq 1$.